# Can I use one word to mean "what is even worse"?

Tags: synonyms

I'm describing the harm that a thing causes.

> First, it creates more losses.  What is even worse is that it creates instability issues.

Is there one word that I can use to represent "what is even worse"?

Comment: *Worse yet* isn't one word, but it is shorter.

Comment: Presumably it causes *stability* issues. I would view *instability* issues as a net positive. Bad, worse, even worse, worst.

Answer (score 13):

You can introduce the mention of the additional deficit simply with the word *worse:*

> Worse, it creates instability issues.

Or:

> {Even worse / Worse still}, it creates instability issues.

Answer (score 0):

What about:
Moreso?
Notwithstanding?